# C# "if" and "for"

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement

in C#, if i am using "if" and "for" to ask someone how many products did he/she bought and the prices and show in the program the cheapast and more expensive, how do i do?

Console.WriteLine("How many products will you buy: ");

```
       double amountofproducts = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (double conter = 0; contador < amountofproducts; conter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("insert the price " + (conter + 1) + "º product");
            double price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
        }
        double moreexpensive = 0;
        double cheapest = 0;

        if (moreexpensive > cheapest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The cheapest product is: ");
        }
        else if (moreexpensive < cheapest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The more expensive product is: ");
        }
```

Comment: you should declare your min-max variables before the `for` loop and check inside the loop if the value entered is lower or greater than your min-max variables and, if it is, store in the min or max variables the value the user entered.

Comment: "How do I do it" isn't a very good question. You've posted some code, what's wrong with how that code works? How does it behave that's different from your expectation?

Comment: probably a language related typo, but you are mixing `conter` and `contador`.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/utv0ba)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don’t have an array with the whole elements or even a list which you’re creating items using console, so it’s impossible to compare item by item with the same input of data…

Comment: Link only anwers are problematic because link can get broken and your answer would be lacking

Comment: I remove the link

Comment: my comment was a suggestion to improve your answer adding some content of the link you provided, so if the link got broken your answer would still be useful.